For an objective falling, reaching terminal velocity and then hitting the ground, how can I find the force it exerts on the ground?
For example object with v=tanh(0.1213)t/0.01236. m=69kg.
I thought I had to use F=mv/t but that just gives the net force of the object while falling.
I don't know how to find the force impacting on the ground.

you need more info, like how long it takes to decelerate due to the ground

what formula for the impact force should I use

F=ma...................................

that doesnt work, and that is for constant acceleration

The force will variable across time, unless you just want an average.

yeah do i need energy then?

No, that is seconds' Newton law, it is valid for any force and any time variation of such force or accelerayton

a is not constant. I need to find an equation that uses momentum or energy before and after collision to find force

the equation is also valid for acceleration  not constant

yes I know the terminal velocity

good luck.......

Do you know $\Delta t$ - the time the impact force acts?

you mean the impulse equation? I don't think I have Δt, yet

Well, you need to know how long the object is in contact with the ground before it comes to complete rest (assuming no rebound).

yeah thx. if no rebound then momentum just equals mv

.......Exactly.

Short answer: The given information is not enough.
Long answer: You correctly noted that the force of the impact is related to the change in momentum. We take off from there. If we assume the duration of impact to be $\Delta t$, then we have:
$$F \Delta t = \Delta mv = m \Delta v$$
(the mass of the object does not change in impact)
From the above equation we can see that in addition to $m$, we need two other pieces of information in order to calculate impact force: $\Delta t$ (duration of impact) and $\Delta v$ (change of velocity in impact). The latter may seem a bit confusing, so I expand on it a bit more here.
Imagine that the falling object is a pile of mud. It reaches ground with velocity $v$ and immediately after impact its velocity is $0$. This type of impact is called inelastic (or sometimes called plastic). In this case, $\Delta v = 0 - v = -v$.
Now imagine another object of the same mass and the same velocity $v$ at the beginning of impact. This time, however, suppose that the object bounces back from the ground with velocity $-v$, somewhat like a pingpong ball. This type of impact is called elastic. In this case, $\Delta v = -v - v = -2v$.
Compare the above examples of inelastic and elastic collisions. Note that even if $m$, $v$ and $\Delta t$ are the same in the two examples, their forces of impact differ, because the two cases involve different changes in velocity, and therefore different changes in momentum.
As a final note, collisions in reality are not necessarily perfectly inelastic or perfectly elastic; they may be somewhere in between. In such a case, an additional piece of information that is needed in order to calculate the force of impact is a coefficient quantifying the elasticity of the impact.
Edit: The term inelastic collision is used more frequently than plastic collision. Following Cameron Williams' comment I replaced the word plastic with inelastic.

I have heard the term "completely inelastic" rather than "plastic" in this situation.

@CameronWilliams Thank you. I have heard them both (see for example Britannica entry for 'inelastic collision') but the term 'inelastic' is used more often. So I edited the text following your comment.

You need to know either impact time, as per $$ F = -\frac {p_f}{t_i} $$
Or you need to know impact distance as in, for example meteorite+crater case :
$$ F=\frac {K_f}{d_i} $$
when equating meteorite kinetic energy to work done by impact force,- we can extrapolate force.
Without any impact parameters, it's not possible to calculate force exerted on the ground.
